# Force batch job to wait certain time before it exits

Tags: batch-file

In batch job, how to force batch job to wait certain time before it exits ?

Example the batch job will take about 2 minutes to finish but I would like to force batch job to wait like 5 minutes then only exit. Is it doable ?

Comment: [timeout -t 300 & exit](https://ss64.com/nt/timeout.html) ?

Comment: where should I put this command ?

Comment: at the (logical) end of your batch file (that's where execution ends - not necessarily identical with "end of file")

Comment: Thanks it works........